# Propagators and PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, greens-function, quantum-field-theory, fundamental-solution

In quantum field theory one encounters the retarded, advanced and Feynman propagators as certain solutions to a wave equation. Mathematically, these derivations are somewhat magical (typically one inserts an "infinitesimally small" $\mathrm{i} \varepsilon$ term, and then the different propagators result from different integration contours around certain poles). On the other hand, there is a mathematically rigorous theory of fundamental solutions to PDEs, but I have never seen anything analogous to these propagators in a PDE book. Can somebody recommend a source (book/lecture notes/paper), where the retarded, advanced and Feynman propagators are treated in a mathematically rigorous way, so that I can see the connection between QFT and PDE theory?

In the meantime also posted and answered at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430530/propagators-and-pdes).

Comment: Contour integration is hardly magical, but rather a well studied approach to do complex integrals, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration  Regarding the propagators and the connection between QFT and PDEs, please look for the Green's function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function

Comment: Inserting infinitesimally small quantities into a formula certainly IS magical, and the linked wikipedia page does not contain a rigorous treatment of the propagators I asked about.